# Filter out invalid results in vim-fzf/fzf

Tags: vim, fzf, vim-fzf

I use [fzf.vim](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf.vim) quite a bit in my workflow I have one problem when using `:GFiles`.

In the codebase I work on, we have `src/node_modules` checked into git, so whenever I use `:GFiles` we get a lot of results back, which includes the node_modules contents.

How can I remove items that start with `src/node_modules*` for example from the `:GFiles` command in [fzf.vim](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf.vim)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that `git ls-files` is what `:GFiles` run and the implementation allows for arguments and unix pipes.

The solution is to run grep to filter out the results:

```
map <C-p> :GFiles \| grep -v -E "(node_modules\|bower_components)"<CR>
```